# Gear 2 Neo Not Connecting Galaxy S3 CM11

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-gear

So I was able to get Gear Manager, and it finds the Gear in the list. When I click connect, it just tries to connect forever.

Is there any way to get the gear working, even without Gear Manager?

It is a Galaxy S3 running CM 11 M9. I am open to changing roms if necessary....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look on this [XDA Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2723862) you'll notice your not the only one with this issue, in the forum there is a "Fix forever connecting issue" section which will prompt you to download a file and install it on your phone and it should resolve your issue

By doing this you should be able to get gear manager working properly as if I'm correct its the only way to use the gear 2 (neo) with a mobile device, also switching custom ROM won't fix the issue without doing the above.

Comment: I tried that link before, but the fix didn't work. In fact, it ended up hard bricking my device. I am chalking the hard brick up to user error, but I would be careful using this one. I ended up with a new phone. I am going to mark yours as the answer though, since the link is likely helpful to someone else.